# Help on evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}(\tan x)^ {\tan 2x} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}(\tan x)^ {\tan 2x} = ? $

I know that's an indetermination of the form $1^{\infty}$, but I don't see any way to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method, is using $\ln$

$$\ln(\lim_{x \to \frac\pi4}{\tan x}^{\tan 2x}) = \lim_{x \to \frac\pi4}\ln({\tan x}^{\tan 2x}) = \lim_{x \to \frac\pi4} (\tan 2x) \ln({\tan x})$$

$${\tan 2x} = \frac{2 \tan x}{1 - \tan^2x}$$

So:

$$\ln\left(\lim_{x \to \frac\pi4}{(\tan x)^{\tan 2x}}\right) = \lim_{y \to 1}{ \left(\frac{2y}{1 - y^2}\right) \ln{y}} = \lim_{y \to 1} \left(\frac{2y}{(1 - y)(1 + y)}\right) \ln({y})$$

$$= \lim_{y \to 1} \left(\frac{1}{1 - y}\right) \ln({y}) = -1$$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{x \to \frac \pi4}{{\tan x}^{\tan 2x}} = e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left[\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\left(1+(\tan x-1)\right)^{\frac1{\tan x-1}}\right]^{\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\tan2x(\tan x-1)}$$

The inner limit converges to $e$

For the exponent 
$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\tan2x(\tan x-1)=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{2\tan x(\tan x-1)}{-(\tan x+1)(\tan x-1)}=\cdots=-1$$

as $\tan2A=\dfrac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2A}$

Comment: Making $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1+x)^{1/x} = e$ appear there was beautiful... thanks